# Why matrix to raster shows up rotated?

Tags: r, matrix, rotation, r-raster

I am trying to convert a matrix (`myMat`) to raster data (`myRas`); however, I am not sure **why** this rotates all of a sudden. This can be easily fixed by 90-degree rotation using `t()` but, I will be grateful if someone explains why this unwanted rotation happens all the time?! and if there is a way to prevent it?

```
set.seed(23022019)
library(raster)
library(RColorBrewer)

#myMat
myMat<-matrix(runif(3*3), ncol=3) 
image((myMat), col=rev(brewer.pal(9,"RdYlBu")))

#myRas
myRas <- raster(myMat)
image((myRas), col=rev(brewer.pal(9,"RdYlBu")))
```

[image]

Comment: @www : this is not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14513480/convert-matrix-to-raster-in-r  ---- even if the title suggests that. That question is about creating a RasterLayer from a list with x, y, and z vectors

Comment: @RobertHijmans Sure. Let me re-open it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would argue that `myRas` is not rotated; and that `image(myMat)` is rotated. See below.

```
library(raster) 
myMat<-matrix(1:9, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
myRas <- raster(myMat)

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
image(myMat, col=terrain.colors(9), main="image(myMat)")
plot(myRas,  col=terrain.colors(9), main="plot(raster(myMat))")
text(myRas)
```

[image]

```
myMat
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    2    3
#[2,]    4    5    6
#[3,]    7    8    9
```

What happens is that `image(myMat)` read the values row-wise, and fills the values column-wise, from bottom to top. You may desire that, but it is a rotation. In contrast, `raster(myMat)` keeps the values in the same order.

The help from `graphics::image` explains why it displays the values like this; even if it may be very difficult to follow. If you provide a matrix with values, but not x and y coordinates, the first argument (x) is "used instead of z for convenience". This will give you equally spaced values from 0 to 1 for x and y, and the (z) values are assumed to be in ascending order (starting at the lower left corner and going row-wise!).

Comment: This is one a subtle point of matrix to raster conversion rules. I do not think that in clearly mentioned in their help documents.

Comment: I expanded my answer to explain what graphics::image does. As for `raster`, I do not know what one would say about unexpected things that do *not* happen.